# Order GroupBy Asc based on Two more Properties using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, group-by

My GroupBy is performing well. I'm getting the Output

[image]

> I need to Sort the Group Names
>
> The Brown Color Block, represents the Group.
>
> The Red Color Box within the Brown Color Block, represents the Manager
>
> 1. Peter Block (Brown Box) Should Come first
> 2. Raj Block (Brown Box) Should Come Second
> 3. Sunny Block (Brown Box) Should Come Third
>
> Each Block Should Group By Boss(Manager) and Assistant (Boss don't have the
>   SID). After GroupBy the Name should be in Sorted Order, within the Group 
>   the Assistant Names are also in the Sorted Order.

The Model Classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}

public class Boss
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

The Main Functionality Source Code:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Boss> BossList = new List<Boss>()
    {
        new Boss()
        {
            ID = 101,
            Name = "Sunny",
            Department = "Development",
            Gender = "Male",
            Role = "Manager",
            Employees = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person() {ID = 101, SID = 102, Name = "Peter", Department = "Development", Gender = "Male", Role = "Assistant"},
                new Person() {ID = 101, SID = 103, Name = "Emma Watson", Department = "Development", Gender = "Female", Role = "Assistant"},

            }
        },
        new Boss()
        {
            ID = 104,
            Name = "Raj",
            Department = "Development",
            Gender = "Male",
            Role = "Manager",
            Employees = new List<Person>()
                    {
                        new Person() {ID = 104, SID = 105, Name = "Kaliya", Department = "Development", Gender = "Male", Role = "Assistant"},
                        new Person() {ID = 104, SID = 103, Name = "Emma Watson", Department = "Development", Gender = "Female", Role = "Assistant"},

                    },
        },
        new Boss()
        {
            ID = 102,
            Name = "Peter",
            Department = "Development",
            Gender = "Male",
            Role = "Manager",
            Employees = new List<Person>()
                    {
                        new Person() {ID = 102, SID = 105, Name = "Kaliya", Department = "Development", Gender = "Male", Role = "Assistant"},
                        new Person() {ID = 102, SID = 103, Name = "Emma Watson", Department = "Development", Gender = "Female", Role = "Assistant"},

                    }
        }
    };

    List<Person> EmpList = BossList.SelectMany(i =>
        new[] {
                new Person()
                {
                    ID = i.ID,
                    SID = i.SID,
                    Name = i.Name,
                    Gender = i.Gender,
                    Department = i.Department,
                    Role = i.Role
                }
        }.Concat(i.Employees)
    ).ToList().GroupBy(s => s.ID).SelectMany(h => h.GroupBy(g => g.SID).SelectMany(u => u.OrderBy(k=> k.Name))).ToList();
}
```

Comment: So if I get you right you just want the groups to be sorted? Could you add how your picture should look like if you have the result you want?

Comment: @Nitro.de - The Screen apex is not giving the expected output. I need the changes for that Output Screen as said in Yellow Quotes.

Answer (score -1):

You can do by adding the ThenBy extension method after the Order by to apply the secondary sort. In fact, the ThenBy can be called multiple times for sorting on multiple property. I have modified the last line of your code to show how you can achieve this.

```
).ToList().GroupBy(s => s.ID).SelectMany(h => h.GroupBy(g => g.SID).SelectMany(u => u.OrderBy(k=> k.Name).ThenBy(l => l.<<secondproperty>>))).ToList();
```

Comment: fails means not error throwing. It just returns just as like my output. Give your answer with appropriate Source Code...

Comment: Can you provide the code that you tried? I'm interested in what is your second property in the expression? ThenBy(l => l.<<secondproperty>>)

Comment: In the Yellow Quoted Box I mentioned clearly what I need. Kindly refer the Output Screen and Yellow Quoted Requirement. The Question is not Order By two Properties, "Order GroupBy Asc based on Two more Properties using LINQ C#". Kindly ready the post.

Answer (score -1):

The datastructure already establishes the groups.  There is no need to re-group.

```
List<Person> result = (
  from boss in BossList
  order by boss.Name
  let orderedEmployees = boss.Employees.OrderBy(emp => emp.Name)
  let bossPerson = new Person(boss)
  let people = new List<Person>() { bossPerson }.Concat(orderedEmployees)
  from person in people
  select person).ToList();
```

If you prefer the lambda syntax:

```
List<Person> result = BossList
  .OrderBy(boss => boss.Name)
  .SelectMany(boss => {
    IEnumerable<Person> orderedEmployees = boss.Employees.OrderBy(emp => emp.Name);
    Person bossPerson = new Person(boss);
    return new List<Person>() { bossPerson }.Concat(orderedEmployees);
  })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: The Person Model Class don't have any parameter constructor. Kindly check it once pls.

Comment: Use equivalent code.  You convert a Boss to a Person in the question so you know how to do it.